# Certificates are not valid startup message

Tags: 20.04, startup, certificates

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Two weeks ago the following message started to pop up during the startup process: "Certificates are not valid, you must be logged in as root to create new ones." I really do not know what I've done to cause such behavior.

[image: pop up messsage]

Could anyone help me to solve this little issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A message like this points more to certificates that have expired rather than something you may have done. The question is really more about *which* certificates have expired, as it doesn’t seem to be preventing you from using the machine. What message do you see when you run `sudo update-ca-certificates` in Terminal? 

Comment: This is the message after running the sudo update-ca-certificates command:
**'Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.'**

Comment: Hmm ... we'll need to see if there is anything in the logs to say *which* certificates need to be updated, then. Could you take a look in `/var/log/syslog` to see if there are any messages complaining about certificates from around the time you signed into the machine and received this error?

Comment: Just a simple check: is your system date and time (and timezone) correct?

Comment: thanks @matigo everything seems to be ok

Comment: Thanks @matigo everything seems to be ok (or not? I had to trim the text cause it's too long):

Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
blacklist: Loading compiled-in revocation X.509 certificates
integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
Revoking X.509 certificate: UEFI:dbx
integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:MokListRT (MOKvar table)
cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.

Comment: Thanks @FedKad but the system date/time/timezone are correct.